# Limit the number of objects in django TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I use Django, and I want create a TabularInline showing a maximum of 10 results

You can configure it with `max_num` and `extra`, but that does not limit the results.

They have a [special section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects) on "Limiting the number of editable objects".
Where they say "max_num does not prevent existing objects from being displayed".
But also not how its actually done.

I can also not overwrite the get_queryset method because Django does a filter later and then I get `TypeError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.`

Does anyone know how I can do this?

---

So I decided to do it like this, because I cant find a better way.

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        ids = qs.values_list('id', flat=True).all()[:10]
        qs = CreditsTransaction.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        return qs
```

But I'm not really satisfied with this.

Comment: can you add the source code with what you have tried so far?